# Postitioning with fixed navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I'm currently developing a website and I'm looking to have a sticky navbar. I've got it all working, but it seems that when I scroll down the page, the navbar goes underneath the page content, rather then overtop of it. I've checked all my z-index's, and they're all fine; so it's not that.

I've posted my jfiddle below, but it's the first time I've done a jfiddle, so tell me if I need to add something.

Thanks!

http://bit.ly/18GeDts

Thanks so much for your help guys, turns out it was my stupid commenting. Usually that stuff is supposed to help you.

The problem is, on my live site, it still wont work. The background of the nav on my live site  is an image, and it seems like that doesn't carry over.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't have jQuery enabled. Once I pick jQuery in the dropdown, it works fine.

Comment: @JoeSimmons got there first but here it is with jQuery enabled http://jsfiddle.net/Gguxx/8/

Comment: @JoeSimmons it does work, but as you can see in the jsfiddle, the background of the nav doesn't follow. I need the background to be there as well, so when it scrolls over the content, you can't see any.

Comment: working fine for me, your css in fidle was as well commented http://jsfiddle.net/Gguxx/28/

Comment: The issue in any specific platfor/browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to remove this bit at the top of your CSS section in the fiddle:

```
* NAVIGATION **************************************************/
```

Then it will work perfectly, your code is fine :)

Comment: Huh, you're totally right. Why doesn't this work on the live site.

Comment: can you give us a link to the live site then we can have a look.

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment due to low reputation so im posting it here.

```
* NAVIGATION **************************************************/
```

is messing up with your css rules. Removing it will make your sticky header work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If im putting to .navbar-collapse.collapse a position fixed its working  `enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/ucRe/a

Answer (score -1):

z-index only works on positioned elements. For example:

```
.nav-container {
  z-index: 99;
  position: relative;
}
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: I've added the position, but still nothing. I also added a position and a z-index to the content, but nothing either.

Comment: Why the down vote? Adding a position is required when using z-index. This might not have solved your problem, but its still proper CSS http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: I downvoted you because he is clearly using a plugin that sets the position already, as commented in the fiddle. Your answer was redundant.